# Adding a live address link inside a shape description for a kml file

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz

I have a description inside my KML for all my shapes,

And I’m trying to add a live link that represents the shape location on our network

So I can just click on the link and open the location for the specific shape,

Im using the following html tag [as an example]

```
   <tr>
    <td>Link:</td>
    <td><a> href="C:\Users\Name\Downloads"></a></td>
  </tr>
```

This shows the link but without the hyperlink beneath it,

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I believe you have a syntax error. You have `<a>`. Try removing the `>` from that. I don't know if that will fix it, though.

Comment: When i do that, even the text "C:\Users\Name\Downloads" disappears!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the closing angle bracket from the a element opener. You have invalid html markup right there.

```
 <tr>
    <td>Link:</td>
    <td><a> href="C:\Users\Name\Downloads"></a></td>
  </tr>
```

should be:

```
 <tr>
    <td>Link:</td>
    <td><a href="C:\Users\Name\Downloads" target="_blank">C:\Users\Name\Downloads</a></td>
  </tr>
```

To stop the link opening inside the ongowindow try using target="_blank"

Comment: When i do that, even the text "C:\Users\Name\Downloads" disappears!!

Comment: That would be because I forgot to add the text in outside of the tag as geocodezip has just fixed. That's what I get for answering questions at midnight after work. Thanks geocodezip. Google-maps hero.

Comment: I checked the "allow access to local files and personal data" under Tools>Options>General. But now it tries to load it inside the description box and then crashes Google earth!!

Comment: Updated answer with fix.

Comment: Ok the folder does open now [which is what i want], but google earth displays an error message "An error occurred while loading this page", so its trying to open the folder inside google earth too,

Comment: I had to check: Tools>options>General>Display>Show web results in external browser
And now its working